# Save image for offline use html 5 web application

Tags: ipad, html

I have large set of image arround 60 MB. I want to use these images offline, in a html5 web application. Currently I am storing image data in a sqlite table but it seems ipad safari does not support more than 50 MB of data.

Is there any way to store data in the folders at client side/ipad and then use them through javascript code or there is any alternative way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the File System API, however the limitations may vary in different browsers and OSs.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System/Introduction